# T-SQL : CREATE FUNCTION must be the only statement in batch

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am required to write a function to get the average grade of a student in T-SQL.

This is my code attempt:

```
create function averageGrade(@id int)
returns float
as
begin
    declare @av float

    select @av = AVG(Grade) 
    from Take 
    where StudentNo = @id

    return @av;
end;
```

but I get an error

> CREATE FUNCTION must be the only statement in batch

I can't for the life of me figure it out. I have seen that it will work if I changed it to an inline or multi-statement UDF, but I need to use this function on a

Comment: @LukStorms yes thank you i just need to surround it with go

Comment: Just an aside ... you can trim your function down to ...  return (select avg(grade) from Take where StudentNo=@id )

Comment: @RonenAriely Would you believe that SO wrote that message?

Comment: Sry, I don't understand your question. I assume that by `SO` you mean stackoverflow, and I don't understand what you mean by `stackoverflow wrote that message`. I see the comment which you wrote `Does this answer your question? <link here>` which answered the OP question - so this should be the answer

Comment: @RonenAriely When you vote for closure because of duplicate, then StackOverflow generates a message in your name.

Comment: Ohhhh... Thanks @LukStorms, this is new for me `:-)` One more issue I don't like in SO... We are stuck with an open question now. At least it was generate the message as an answer instead of as comment, then it was making more sense to me